# Android data usage control / tracking?

Tags: android

Our company giving out Android devices to drivers. Our application should never use more then 1Gb by nature of communications we do.

However, some drivers managed to use about 10Gb of data :)

So, I wonder:

1. Is there any way to track data usage of our app vs other apps so we can notify users and office workers?
2. Is there any way to DISABLE data access from any app other then ours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to track data usage of our app vs other apps so we can notify users and office workers?

As H9kDroid indicates, use `TrafficStats`. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtuning/tree/master/TrafficMonitor) that takes an initial snapshot of the consumed bandwidth, then takes another one when you tap a button, displaying the overall difference on-screen and the per-UID difference in LogCat. Note that not all devices support the per-UID stuff (e.g., not the Ice Cream Sandwich emulator).

> Is there any way to DISABLE data access from any app other then ours?

No, sorry. Eventually, the combination of device admin rules and the new traffic management stuff in Ice Cream Sandwich's Settings app might allow for this, but not presently. Or, you could create custom firmware.

Comment: What about parental control apps on market? Those can prevent access to applications? I can block market and apps that preinstalled, right?

Comment: @katit: "Those can prevent access to applications?" -- only for people who aren't trying very hard. Removing such a filter is one reboot away.

Comment: Actually, prove me wrong, I just installed Parental Control app and disabled Market. Reboot didn't help - still asked me for password. This might be something..

Comment: How about this idea? Our app runs a service. What if I create service with the same principle as those Parental Control apps? They can do whatever but as long as my app runs (which is what they must have) - other apps will be controlled?

Comment: @katit: Fortunately, this is not possible, as malware would love to use this technique.

Comment: Understood what you said. This Parental Control app works, it runs as a service, right? Ok. I can reboot in safe mode and uninstall. Great. In my scenario - it's company issued device with my app. If my app does what Parental Control do - users have no way of disabling it because if they uninstall my app - they basically messing with company installed stuff. So, technically it becomes "must have". They can't get away with using my app and disabling it at the same time. That should work, right?

Comment: @katit: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by "controlled". You are welcome to try whatever you like.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html), with help of that you can get the amount of data sent/received. And you can get the data by UIDs to see where it was used.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that TrafficStats only calculates the amount of data sent/received since the last boot, not overall.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way to DISABLE data access from any app other then ours?

If rooting the devices is an option then you can use the free Application [DroidWall](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5nb29nbGVjb2RlLmRyb2lkd2FsbC5mcmVlIl0.) This application makes use of the iptables rules of linux to let you allow / disallow applications from using network data.